# Magento 2 - Save data to multiple tables not working

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, save, table, data

I have created a custom module having two tables named *helloworld_post* and *helloworld_tag* and from front-end side I want to save fields values to these 2 tables. However I have created two respective models as well but its only working for *helloworld_post* not for *helloworld_tag*. Can anyone help me please?

**Below is my code :**

> Post model - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Model/Post.php

```
namespace CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

const CACHE_TAG = 'helloworld_post';
protected $_cacheTag = 'helloworld_post';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'helloworld_post';
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
}
public function getIdentities()
{
    return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
}
public function getDefaultValues()
{
    $values = [];
    return $values;
}
}
```

> Post resource model -app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Model/ResourceModel/Post.php

```
namespace CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{   

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}   
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('CompanyName_helloworld_post', 'post_id');
}   
}
```

> Tag model - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Model/Tag.php

```
namespace CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model;

class Tag extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel 
implements   \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

const CACHE_TAG = 'helloworld_tag';
protected $_cacheTag = 'helloworld_tag';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'helloworld_tag';
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Tag');
}
public function getIdentities()
{
    return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
}
public function getDefaultValues()
{
    $values = [];
    return $values;
}
}
```

> Tag resource model - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Model/ResourceModel/Tag.php

```
namespace CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;

class Tag extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{   

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}   
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('helloworld_tag', 'tag_id');
}   
}
```

> Controller - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Display.php

```
namespace CompanyName\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

protected $_pageFactory;
protected $_postFactory;
protected $_tagFactory;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\TagFactory $tagFactory
) {
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    $this->_tagFactory = $tagFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}      

public function execute() { 
    $model = $this->_postFactory->create();
    $model2 = $this->_tagFactory->create();
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    if (isset($post) && !empty($post)) {
      //Save data for first table
       $model->setData($post['party']);
       $model->setName($post['party']['name']);
       $model->save();
        //Save data for second table
        $model2->setData($post['party']);
        $model2->setName($post['party']['address']);
        $model2->save();  
    } 
     return $this->_pageFactory->create();
 }

 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the Magento logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced __construct method with following code and deleted var/generation/.It's working fine.

> Controller - app/code/CompanyName/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Display.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,            
    \CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,      
    \CompanyName\HelloWorld\Model\TagFactory $tagFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory

) {
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    $this->_tagFactory = $tagFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
```